# I'm confused about the identity of Stirling numbers: $s(n,k) = k!S(n,k)$

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I'm a little bit confused about this identity between Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, because from it you can derive that:

$s(n,k) = k!S(n,k) = k!(S(n-1,k-1) + kS(n-1,k)) = k(k-1)!S(n-1,k-1) + kk!S(n-1, k) = ks(n-1,k-1) + ks(n-1,k) = k(s(n-1,k-1) + s(n-1, k))$.

But the identity for Stirling numbers of the first kind is known and it's

$s(n,k) = s(n-1,k-1) + (n-1)s(n-1,k)$.

Have I mistaken somewhere or both identites are correct?

Comment: I never knew that!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sometimes Stirlings of first kind are defined as $k!S(n,k)$, where S(n,k) are Stirlings of the second kind. it makes sense if ou consider the first kind as a count of surjections from a set of size $n$ onto a set of size $k$ (you can read more about it here, for example: https://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul945/HILT-P~1.PDF)

Comment: But those are not Stirling numbers of the first kind as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

Comment: Nowhere in that pdf you cite are the Stirling numbers of the first kind defined as $k! S(n,k)$, and furthermore I have heard of no one else using this definition. It would be incredibly confusing to do so, considering as how the Stirling numbers of the first kind are already widely known as the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $k$ cycles.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you define Stirling numbers of the first kind as

   > The number of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with exactly $k$ cycles,

   then the equation $s(n,k)=s(n-1,k-1)+(n-1)s(n-1,k)$ is correct.
2. If you define Stirling numbers of the first kind as

   > The number of surjective functions from a set of size $n$ to one of size $k$,

   them the equation $s(n,k)=k\big(s(n-1,k-1)+s(n-1,k)\big)$ is correct.

These two cannot be correct simultaneously.

Your confusion results from the fact you are using the same symbol, $s(n,k)$, for two different quantities.